# How do I migrate a Git TFS Azure Repository with History

Tags: git, azure, tfs

I have been working on this for a few days without much luck.  I have a Git TFS Repository in Azure with multiple branches.  Example:

```
ProjectFoo
  -Development
  -Master
  -Release 1.0
```

All branches have history since we have been working in them for months.  We need to move this code to a new Git Repository in Azure an retain history with branches.

I have been researching ways to do this.  It looks like Git TF might work (with --deep) but I can't get it to find my repository when I run the clone command.

```
C:\Users\Tom>git tf clone https://myrepo.com/DefaultCollection/_git/ProjectFoo  $/ProjectFoo ProjectFoo --deep
Connecting to TFS...
Username: tom
Password:
```

I get the following Error:

```
git-tf: Could not find a valid TFS Collection at
https://myrepo.com/DefaultCollection/_git/ProjectFoo
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here or what would be the best way to get the code migrated over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git-tf` tool is used for communicating with MSVC/TFVC projects. If your repository is a Git TFS repository, just use ordinary `git clone`. You should have a "clone" button in the web UI which will give you the proper URL to pass to `git clone`. You may also have to set up alternate credentials in your project settings, as Git doesn't understand Microsoft Live accounts.

Comment: Will git clone retain history?  That's the only reason I was going down the git-tf route.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `git clone` clones the full commit history (including all branches) from the repository.